# This app is already being monetized: The app you're attempting to add is already being monetized by a business in Facebook audience network?

Tags: facebook, networking, audience

I want to monetize my android app by face audience network but whenever I try to add my app link This app is already being monetized: The app you're attempting to add is already being monetized by a business.
Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Please share how you fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to get in touch with Facebook for this (https://business.facebook.com/business/help/support).

In my case, I deleted a Facebook Property that had previously claimed the app Play Store's link. They will send you an e-mail asking you to confirm that you own the app.

Comment: Hi, How long does it take for them to resolve the issue? I've been waiting for almost a week now.

Comment: Going through the e-mails they resolved my issue within 2 days. Is the link in my answer above still working?

Comment: Thanks.
I've transferred my app to another company and deleted my facebook property. Now the company tries to create an ad account but facebook gives this silly error. I've contacted them for more than two weeks but still they haven't resolved it yet.

Comment: now the link is not valid either